# Battery shows 100% charged but netbook does not work without AC adapter

Tags: battery, power, netbook

How can I test if the battery is connected internally to my netbook or if it is working? Is it possible that the battery has been disabled by a software setting? The battery shows 100% charged, but the netbook shuts down if the AC adapter cable is unplugged, so the battery is not kicking in to keep the netbook operating.

Comment: May be time to replace your laptop's battery! Just check out if anyone have the same model and try to put his battery in your laptop and see what happen? Or may be any hardware issue so battery is not getting charged? :\

Comment: If your netbook is still under warranty, call and ask the manufacturer/retailer for a replacement battery, also.

Answer (score 3):

I think your netbook's battery has gone kaput. You can verify this in several ways by either installing an application like [Battery Care](http://batterycare.net/en/index.html) or [CPUID HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)
[image: Battery Care reporting battery wear levels]

Or you could use Windows' **powercfg** tool to check your battery health. Use this command:

```
powercfg /batteryreport (if you're running Windows 8. This doesn't require privilege elevation)
```

```
powercfg -energy (if you're on Windows 7/8. This requires that you run the command using an elevated command prompt and profiles your battery usage for 60 seconds to create a report)
```

That'll create a battery health report which will show the battery's design capacity as well as its current capacity.
[image: powercfg battery report]

You might also want to [calibrate your battery](http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html#descTot) so that it reports correct battery information.

Comment: On my Windows 7 laptop `powercfg –batteryreport` doesn't work: `Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help`. `/?` doesn't say anything about `-batteryreport`.

Comment: Sorry about that. The command is `powercfg /batteryreport`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @gronostaj The batteryreport switch is Windows 8 only. On Windows 7 do `powercfg -energy`. It will take 1-2 minutes, be patient. Then it spits out an HTML file; open it up and scroll down towards the bottom (or search the document for "design capacity") and you'll see a section that matches the one described in this answer.

Comment: @Vinayak It actually doesn't matter, it recognizes both `-batteryreport` and `/batteryreport` - many Windows command line tools support interchangeable `-` and `/` for options. It's just that it's not in the Windows 7 version of `powercfg`.

Comment: It's just the weirdest thing, but I ran the same command (`powercfg -batteryreport`) on my friend's computer right now and it didn't work. Then I used `/` instead of `-` and it worked. Then after reading your comment, I tried it with the `-` again (I copy+pasted, so no typing errors) and it worked! Windows just drives me crazy sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

You can test to see if the battery is connected internally by removing the battery while the netbook is on and plugged in.  If the netbook tells you that the battery has been removed after you actually remove it... and then acknowledges that you just inserted a battery after you actually put it back in, then your netbook is correctly connecting to the battery.

If one or more of the cells within the battery are bad/defective, they can make the battery report a full/100% charge while being charged but then fail when under load.  Another common symptom of a failing/defective cell in a laptop battery is what appears to be a normal drain until somewhere between 50%-20%, then immediate drop to almost 0%.

It is not uncommon for one cell within a laptop/netbook battery to fail.  Depending on the make of netbook or laptop, and whether the battery is an extended life model, there are usually between 3 and 6 cells within a netbook/laptop battery... not that this range is definitive by any means, for there are 8, 9, and 12 cell batteries out there as well for some models.  I don't believe I've ever seen one with fewer than 3 though.

I can't say for sure, since I don't have your netbook in front of me, but the chances are good that this is just your netbook telling you to purchase a new battery.

Answer (score 0):

What makes your Laptop turn off when Unplugged?

Update or upgrade windows 10

If you’ve recently upgraded the operating system of your laptop to Windows 10 or updated to the 1809 update, maybe this is the reason for the issue.

Faulty battery

On the off chance that your PC closes down once you unplug the connector, it normally implies your battery isn't working as expected.

As we care about you so arrange some solutions that may fix your problem.

Comment: Your last sentence sounds good but does not have a good meaning in native English.