# Battery is shown as fully charged but does not feed the laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, power, acer-aspire

My laptop is a young Acer V11 Touch (V3-112P-P2E7). Yesterday I used it regularly on battery mode and I left it charging overnight. This morning's surprise is that the laptop only works when connected to the power supply. The system diagnostics say the battery is fully charged though (see figure).

[image: power statistics dialogue]

I am aware of [this other post](https://superuser.com/questions/621742/battery-shows-100-charged-but-netbook-does-not-work-without-ac-adapter) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/965192/why-is-the-battery-dead-inspite-of-the-full-charge-the-previous-day) that address the same topic but deal with Windows tools only.

Beside the mere evidence that the power supply on battery is malfunctioning (possibly for good), I am interested in checking out this issue in Linux and gather arguments to approach the vendor. For example, it could be that the battery diagnostics are right and the problem lies on an another element.

The questions are:

- is the battery the only possible culprit of this kind of issue?
- what are the Linux tools to correctly diagnose the effective situation of a battery?
- which advanced metrics/parameters indicate an anomaly in the battery?

Thanks for thinking along.

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: Less than 2 year old and it is the original piece.

Answer (score 0):

It may be battery damage. You should change your battery, or you can also change your charger too.

Comment: That may be true, but it doesn't answer the question of how to detect battery issues in Linux. Once you have sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment everywhere.

Comment: Your link isn't even pointing to a charger/battery